# 2 delegates of one class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I use delegates to run some methods.

I got class webrequests with 2 delegates: menuVC and mapVC.

When I in mapVC webrequests is accomplish delegates methods of mapVC class.

When I in menuVC webrequests is tried to accomplish delegates methods of mapVC class and crashed app.

Method in webrequests do not helps

```
            if ([self.delegate isKindOfClass: [MenuViewController class]])
            {
                self.delegate = [MapViewController class];
            }
```

Why it happens?

I use in both classes

```
      self.webRequests = [WebRequests sharedInstance];
      self.webRequests.delegate = self;
```

Comment: You have several serious misunderstandings here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Original answer:***

You can only have one delegate of an object at one time, unless the object is designed to allow for different delegate protocols (e.g. UITableView has both a "`delegate`" AND a "`datasource`").

You also **can not** set your delegate to a non-instantiated object like what you are doing on this line:

```
self.delegate = [MapViewController class];
```

This needs to be an actual allocated and instantiated object.

Like "`self.mapViewController`" that you just pushed or created.

For this question, you probably need to better explain what you are ultimately trying to do, since it looks like your current delegate is a MenuViewController object and you're trying to switch the delegate to a MapViewController object.

***New answer:***

Since you want things to happen in two different view controllers, the best way to do what you want to do is use a "`NSNotification`" (which allow multiple objects to observe -- or watch -- for things happening).

[Here is a tutorial you can look at, to get a good start with it](http://zeroheroblog.com/ios/notifications-in-ios-part-1-broadcasting-events-via-nsnotificationcenter).

Comment: I am not certain what you are trying to do, by switching delegates in this way.

Comment: I want that my webrequest run methods from 2 viewControllers

Comment: Since you have multiple view controllers that you want to fire when something happens, consider using a NSNotification.  I've amended my answer for you, and hope this helps!